# Is there a way to map one url to another in Play Framework

Tags: playframework

I'm using Play Framework 2.4.3.  I want to change some of the urls in my routes file, but it turns out there's a database table that has a column of urls. (The user is shown a list of alerts, and each one has a link to the page to which the alert applies.)

I might be able to update the data in the database with the new urls, or translate them at run-time, but I thought a potentially easier solution would be to somehow map the old urls to the new ones.  So for example, my routes file looks like this:

```
#this is the new url
GET /views/producers/:partyId   controllers.ProducerController.viewProducer(partyId:Integer)

#this is the old url
GET /producer/view/:partyId     controllers.ProducerController.viewProducer(partyId:Integer)
```

In the table I have values that look like this:

> /producer/view/123

I can make it work by keeping both entries in the routes file.  Reverse routing will pick up the first one, and both links work.  But I would rather not have the controller function listed twice (and risk them becoming out of sync), and I also would rather have the user see the same url in the browser regardless of how they got there.

Is there a way I can map the old url to the new url?

Comment: I would recommend you update the URL's in the database because there is no 'clean' way to solve this by changing the routes file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving urls in the database doesn't seem a very good idea, but you can make the old url to the new one like this:

```
#this is the new url
GET /views/producers/:partyId   controllers.ProducerController.viewProducer(partyId:Integer)

#this is the old url
GET /producer/view/:partyId     controllers.ProducerController.oldViewProducer(partyId:Integer)
```

Where the oldViewProducer method redirects to the new route:

```
public static Result oldViewProducer(Integer partyId) {
    return redirect(routes.ProducerController.viewProducer(partyId));
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for something nicer, but I guess this is the only way.  It does solve the problem of showing the correct url to the user.